# VSCode three dots at the top of the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

As soon as I start typing anything, three dots show up at the top of the editor screen, which "shifts" my code below one string. How can I turn off this feature, which seems to be useless?

[image]

Comment: looks like the breadcrumb area, you can switch it off in setting: `"breadcrumbs.enabled": false`

Comment: @rioV8 thanks but that didn't work

Comment: Is it some kind of Codelens generated by any extension, disable all extensions and try again

Comment: I've never seen that - I suspect it is one of your extensions doing it.

Answer (score 18):

I toggled off the Code Lens option in the GitLens settings - that did the job

[image]

Comment: It is better to turn off `Gitlens › CodeLens › RecentChange` and keep the useful `CodeLens` functionality. Details in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the extension **GitLens** is causing the issue

Comment: you can use comments for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Turn off (uncheck) **only** `Gitlens › CodeLens › RecentChange` and keep the rest of the **CodeLens** functionality:

[image]

The image below shows what `Gitlens › CodeLens › RecentChange` contols. The text *"Eric Amondio, 3 minutes ago | 1 author (Eric Amondio)"* will be hidden if the option is turned off.

[image]

*Note: Even though the answer provided by kschnack will also fix the problem, you should turn off only the specific option and not the whole Gitlens › CodeLens functionality.*

Comment: VSCode v1.64.2, GitLens  v12.0.0, the setting was found by going to the GitLens gear settings menu -> open settings (opens big ghastly unsearchable settings list) -> 2nd block titled Git CodeLens -> settings subsection titled "Add CodeLens to the following scopes" -> File scope. Unchecking "File scope" made it so the file doesn't bounce on every change/save.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, `SHOWEOL` extension cause this. disable it.

Answer (score 0):

[svet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71322230) to disable recent changes in VS Code settings didn't quite remove the inline GitLens comments for me, but disabling authors as well did:

Searching for `gitlens recent change`:

[image]

Searching for `gitlens authors`:

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Note that hovering over the selected line's GitLens comment to show the popup still works:

[image]